# How to Delete folder older than 7 days C# / NET

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net

I want to write some code that deletes all DIRECTORIES older than 7 days.

So:

1. Check directory : `D:\this`
2. If folder older than  7  days -> delete it from the system.

Comment: Similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222348/how-to-delete-files-older-than-3-months-old-in-a-directory-using-net

Comment: no, thats files, i want directories

Comment: You can get them. They have a date created, the answer can be easily adapted with a truly trivial amount of effort on your part.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can lookup using the DirectoryInfo util

```
   DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
   if (d.CreationTime    < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7))
       d.Delete();
```

Comment: last acces time are to be date created or?

Comment: This will throw exception "the directory is not empty" in case if the directory is not empty. Use `Directory.Delete(dir, true)` if u want to delete directory and all of its content

Answer (score 3):

You can use DirectoryInfo

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx

The voice of experience says to include sanity checks in your code that the directories you are deleting are in fact ones that you want to be deleting...