# Deleting files from directory with creation date filter

Tags: c#, io

I am trying to delete all pdf files older than 1 hour, I am using this code

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PDFFilesPath"]);
var files = directory.GetFiles("*.pdf").Where(f => DateTime.Now.Subtract(f.CreationTime).TotalMinutes >= int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinutesOld"]));
foreach (var file in files)
{
    file.Delete();
}
```

The code is working fine and as expected.

But I am wondering if there is any way to not use foreach or any other smaller approach to 
achieve this

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with `foreach` ? Your approach looks fine to me.

Comment: You can't delete them all at once, if that's what you mean. You could use `Parallel.ForEach` to run them in parallel though (.Net 4 and 4.5)

Comment: using foreach is the best way or i should say the simplest! :-)

Comment: Run this code on the background thread would be better if you delete many files

Comment: The `foreach` **is** the smaller part of this, I'd say... =) But, to shorten your code you could shorten the qualified references by putting your namespaces in `using` statements at the top.

Comment: Define _smaller approach_. In terms of eficiency `foreach` is the most effiicent approach since it doesn't create something new(like a `List<FileInfo>`).

Comment: @TimSchmelter - From smaller approach I mean anything in my code that can be achieved better in the sense of lesser code and performance. I was afraid if I am doing it correctly to process and delete one file at a time, so something like deleting all the files at once etc. However reading all the comments I think the approach is okay.

Comment: @PawanNogariya: Even if there would be something which appears to delete all at once in a single line, it would use a loop implicitely. In terms of simplicity and readability i also cannot imagine something better than your `foreach`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Great then! I will stick with my code now. Actually my main concern was to know if the code is good enough from performance perspective.

Comment: @PawanNogariya: The only thing i see at the first sight is that you could replace `directory.GetFiles` with `directory.EnumerateFiles`. The  latter(new in 4) does't need to load all into memory before it starts processing.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Great! Thanks Tim! Replaced it with `EnumerateFiles`. So you mean it will not load the files with EnumerateFiles until it filter's the files with creationdate? BTW I have changed my code to this now directory.EnumerateFiles("*.pdf").Where(f => DateTime.Now.Subtract(f.CreationTime).TotalMinutes >= int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinutesOld"])).ToList().ForEach(f => f.Delete());

Comment: Try [Codereview.stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you want to review or enhance working code

Comment: @Dark.Amer - +1 Right info :)

Answer (score 0):

You might use LINQ adding the below at the end of your Linq code.

```
.ToList()
    .ForEach(f => f.Delete());
```

Bear in mind that even Linq behind the scene will use an iterator; I would leave as it is then

have a look at this answer as well

[Delete files older than 3 months old in a directory using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222348/how-to-delete-files-older-than-3-months-old-in-a-directory-using-net)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a one liner you could use:

```
files.ToList<FileInfo>().ForEach((FileInfo f) => { f.Delete(); });
```

But this is inefficient and there really isn't any point to it. You're doing it the right way at the moment.

See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) for more info.